# MYSQL insert records skipping ids (Auto Increment)

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I'm quite a new php programmer and cannot seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with inserting records into my MySQL database:

My test script (for learning purpose) calls the eBay API and downloads the requested information into the MySQL database but I seem to be getting the issue of the script skipping IDs on the Auto Increment. From what I have been reading here this is normally when records have been deleted but this is not the case for me as none have been deleted and the gaps get bigger and bigger.

My question is: Is there something else that can cause the id to skip random numbers?

Database example:
Number run from 1-21 just fine but then goes: 28,43,51,55,58
I have checked and next to be added should be 59:

```
show create table 'tbl'
```

Comment: show us your php code, sql insert and table create

Comment: failed/rolled-back transactions will also lead to this. IDs are NOT reused/recycled. Is the lack of sequentiallness causing a problem?

Comment: are you passing id with the insert query???

Comment: Hi,
Dave I would post this but it has a lot of sensitive data, I can email it if this helps? but I am looking more for information then a quick fix. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Marc, I would like to use the IDs as order numbers but having them non-sequential would not be the best. There should not be any rolled back but I will check to see if any have failed, is there a way to stop this?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Sabari, I have the ID in the INSERT query but the value is set to NULL, I believe this will cause it to add one?
Thanks

Comment: There is no way to stop that. That's how your DB works. Use a field of it's own where you keep track of that. Make it unique as well so you know there ain't a duplicate. And please ask only one question per question. You can ask two separately if you like instead (I removed the second question)

Comment: Hi hakre,
Okay no problems I will do that. I'm just still none the wiser to why they are being skipped, as I said this is more for education then application but I am learning! :)

Thanks for your help and apologies for the double question

Comment: I'm with @hakre. You are fighting a losing battle trying to keep an identity column gap free. That is not what identity fields are designed to do.

Comment: @user1166742: It's because the database decides which value to pick. This depends on how the database works. And the database needs to prioritize on some points, e.g. when two processes try to (potentially) insert a new row *at the same time* and these cases. It's just that it is so. [`MAX(orderno) + 1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max).

Comment: @user1166742: Also post your code (remove the sensitive data), otherwise others can't answer your question (or give good suggestions).

Comment: Hi John/Hakre,
Thanks for coming back to me, I understand what you are saying now, I am changing my script and will report back. 
I will make sure to post all the information in the future but you have given me enough to work with here I understand this is bad practise.

Kind Regards,
David

Answer (score 4):

Is your code using transactions? If you rollback a transaction that inserts into that table it doesn't roll back the identity counter even if the transaction gets rolled back.

See this question: [MySQL table with AUTO_INCREMENT primary id does not release the number after a rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750652/mysql-table-with-auto-increment-primary-id-does-not-release-the-number-after-a-r).

Comment: Hi John,
The script does pull transactions but should enter them all into the database as they as sorted after this. There have been none removed/rolledback as to test I will empty the database and retrieve 25 new ones which should go in as 1-25 but still seem to skip some ids

Comment: Hi John,
Checked this but I'm not removing any ids so the gap should not be caused by this
Thanks for your time

Comment: I think you misunderstood. If your code is ADDING rows in a transaction that gets rolled back the identity increment won't be rolled back. I didn't say anything about removing ids.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of guessing what the code will look like, since I am too working with PayPal APIs now, but here is a way to let the auto_increment do it's job

This is how my INSERT command looks like and its been always working. But providing some code will definitely help.

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (auto_increment_id, field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('','$field1','$field2','$field3')";
```

> If you leave the first () blank and just put values after VALUES you
>   have to go with every field, but in the way I showed you, you say
>   which field should get what value.

To connect to live database you can use SQLite. They are called database browsers.

Comment: Hi Grigor,
I will give this a try now and see how I get on all though I did think having NULL in the values did the same job?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I actually have not tried having NULL since this way worked always for me.